# if statement does not alert variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https:/code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Button</button>
    <script>
        var user_response='';
        $('button').on('click',ask_a_question);

        function ask_a_question(){

            user_response = prompt('What is your item name?').toLowerCase();

            if (user_response === 'apple')

//Between here is where i dont understand why, 
//when the if statement is true, that it does not "alert" the bucketlist
//variable and then tells the user **"'learn to juggle', 'take a falconry
//class', 'climb mt everest'."** Does this code even make sense?

            alert(bucketList);

            var bucketList = [
                'learn to juggle', 
                'take a falconry class', 
                'climb Mt Everest'
            ];

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Trying to alert something before it's defined is futile

Comment: Put the `alert` after `bucketList`. Alerts are blocking by nature. So the `bucketList` is defined only after you "accept" the alert, that's why you get `undefined`

Comment: Although `var` in javascript is hoisted, assignments are not.   Like everyone is saying, your alerting before you have defined the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to display the values of bucketList before you define them.

Try moving

```
var bucketList = [
    'learn to juggle', 
    'take a falconry class', 
    'climb Mt Everest'
];
```

above `alert(bucketList);`

Answer (score 1):

When I run the code as written, I get the alert saying 'undefined'.

If I move the alert to after where bucketlist is defined, I get the alert displaying the contents of the array.